# reliably stop bash find after n matches

Tags: bash, find

I am trying to find a reliable way of stopping/killing the find operation after eg 10 matches.   Code below illustrates an inelegant example.

```
find . -type f -iname "*.txt" -exec myscript.sh \{\} \;
```

where myscript.sh currently just outputs the name of the file match

I have tried some suggestions found here ,  eg piping into head -n 10  or piping into grep -m 10 .      but these do not reliably stop the find.   Stdbuf preceding to flush things equally does not help.

Is there a reliable method?

I've tried these without success:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.txt" -exec myscript.sh \{\} \; | head -n 10
```

```
find . -type f -iname "*.txt" -exec myscript.sh \{\} \; | head -n 10 && tail -f /var/log/kern.log & read -t 10 ;kill $!
```

```
find . -type f -iname "*.txt" -exec myscript.sh \{\} \; | grep -m .
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `{}`.

Comment: Do you have to use `-exec`? If you pipe the `find` output to `head`, and then use `xargs`, I think it will stop when head reaches the limit.

Comment: What do you mean by "reliably"? If your shell does not reliably stop all processes in a pipeline when the pipeline finishes, that's a bug in your shell. But perhaps you mean "immediately"?

Comment: reliably here means  immediately as you say.   Reliably in that if there are 100 possible matches, but I only want to take the first 10,  then I need to stop the find process continuing to produce and via the pipe,  executing on on the remaining 90 - which I had found with the initial exec implementation.

Comment: This begs the question, does `find` not stop? How do you establish this?

Comment: find in the example posted (using | head etc) did not reliably stop.   Sometimes yes,  sometimes not.

Comment: Or are you trying to say you want to take a batch of ten, then the next ten etc until you have actually processed all the matches from `find`?

Comment: Again, how exactly do you establish that `find` continues to run?

Comment: because it continues to execute in the shell, generating results.   You may see this in your shell with the examples I posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235474/discussion-between-richard-l-and-tripleee).

Answer (score 2):

You can't prevent your `find` command from generating more than 10 matches before terminating. The shell runs `find` and `head` in parallel, and `find` can easily queue up more than ten lines of output in its output buffer before the pipeline is terminated by the shell.

What you *can* do is refactor the pipeline so that you prevent this from showing any symptoms. For example,

```bash
find . -type f -iname "*.txt" -print0 |
head -z -n 10 |
xargs -r0 myscript.sh
```

This relies on several GNU extensions (namely, the `-print0` option to `find` to print file names null-terminated, and the corresponding `-z` option to `head`, and ditto `-0` for `xargs`), so it's not portable, but should work on most Linux distros as well as elsewhere if you install the GNU versions of the standard utilities (maybe then called `gfind`, `ghead`, `gxargs` etc).

The null termination is important for robustness; if you have file names which contain newlines, `head` et al. could chop off a file name in the middle, and of course, `xargs` can't know that some newlines are part of a file name rather than an argument delimiter. And even if you currently don't have any file names whose names contain newlines, you want to guard against this for any solution which isn't a one-off - troubleshooting the problem later on when you do encounter file names with newlines will be tedious and complicated. Perhaps see also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Alternatively, refactor the `-exec`:

```bash
find . -type f -iname "*.txt" -exec sh -c '
    for arg in $(seq 10); do
        myscript.sh "$1"
        shift
    done
    exit 222' _ {} +
```

The `exit 222` should cause `find` to abort with a failure after the first `-exec` invocation. The `+` after `-exec` makes `find` pass in as many arguments as possible, similar to `xargs`. (If the file names are *really* long, and/or your system's `ARG_MAX` is really small, this could receive fewer than ten files in the first invocation, but I consider this corner case to be pathological.)

Comment: GNU `find` 4.8 does not abort after a non-zero exit value from `-exec … {} +`, e.g. `find /usr/share -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "$#"; exit 3' : {} +` returns 1 after several invocations. I think this is in line with [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47_05) (`If the primary expression is punctuated by a <plus-sign>, the primary shall always evaluate as true, …`).

Comment: @urznow Thanks, you're right. I thought I had tested this properly but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

Using parallel,  this fits my requirement

```
find . -type f -iname "*.txt" | head -n 10 | parallel -j1 'myscript.sh {}  '
```

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of `xargs` here? Wouldn't this just act like `cat` since you used `find`'s regular output (without null bytes) but then used `xargs -0`? I think you can just drop `xargs` here, or better use `find ... -print0 | head -zn10 | xargs -0n1 myscript.sh`.

Comment: you are quite right.   With using parallel,  I dont need xargs. Edited.

Comment: This will fail for file names which contain a newline. You can replace `parallel` with `xargs -n 1` which is installed as part of the base system on any POSIX platform.